# How to display the range selection buttons in middle of the chart in highstock js?

Tags: highcharts

I am using highstock js for stock chart. I want to display the range selection buttons in the center of the chart. Please find the snapshots below.

Currently the buttons are in left side of the chart.
[image]

Expected :

[image]
please help me how to do this in highstock js.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please take look at the uservoice topic http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2436599-add-ability-to-change-rangeselector-position

Answer (score 0):

Check the example from Jugal given in Sebastians link.
You can override the render prototype and manually adjust the position. 
For example like this: (forked Jugals fiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/SPhYd/

```
var leftPosition = this.chart.plotLeft+150,
    topPosition = this.chart.plotTop-10
```

Comment: when resizing the window the range selector buttons are coming out of the chart. How can i fix it?

Comment: just write a more dynamic way of setting the offset. instead of hardcoding 150 above. you know the length of all the buttons. something like windowviewport.width/2 - buttons.width/2 should be your offset.

Comment: I have modified the above code with buttons width for left position. Still its moving out of the chart when resize the window. Can you please send me fiddle for this.Thanks.